# how to set variable in DjangoTemplates inside in a loop and use outside

Tags: django, variables, django-templates

I want to set a variable in a loop and use other out a loop but django template not allow me, If i do this in a view then i have to run the loop 2 times, 1 time in a view and other time in a template.. This is not a good idea

I try "set" , "firstof" and 'template tag' also

example code with template tag
@register.simple_tag
def setvar(val=None):
return val

```
{% for x in "15"|loopRunTime %}
    {% if x == 12 %}
      {% setvar x as action %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ action }}
```

2 example is firstof

```
 {% for x in "15"|loopRunTime %}
   {% if x == 12 %} 
      {% firstof x as i %} 
   {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 {{ i }}
```

Comment: Even i have face this problem so many time, Need to run loop 2 time